# Knob JQuery get value from textfile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to make a script that would allow Knob to get a value from a text file every 3 seconds.

I had JS refresh a div that had php check the file and set the value to a variable. The issue was flickering and kept doubling the knob until it crashes chrome.

I tried this with PHP and didn't get far. Anyone have any ideas?

```
<script>
var dataFile = Server.MapPath("count.txt");
Array userData = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
function clock() {
        $h = $(".hour");
        d = new Date(),
        h = "";
    $h.val(h).trigger("change");
    setTimeout("clock()", 1000);
}
clock();
</script>

<input class="knob hour" value="0" data-fgColor="#EB4B4E" data-thickness=".2" readonly data-min="0" data-max="50" data-width="300" data-height="300">
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
$('.dial')
.val(<?php echo file_get_contents("count.txt"); ?>)
.trigger('change');
},3000);
</script>
```

Comment: What you're doing can't possibly work. Use AJAX

Comment: @rjdown how would I do this?